# How can I use assumptions with FindRoot[] in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, equation-solving

In Mathematica I have something like

```
FindRoot[f[x], {x, a}]
```

Now I want FindRoot to constrain the solutions to 0 < x < 1.

How can I obtain this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a four-parameter option for this function: FindRoot[f[x],{x,xstart,xmin,xmax}] which stops the search if the search ventures outside of the interval [xmin,xmax].